# CustomPermissionEvaluator with database

Tags: spring-security

CustomPermissionEvaluator with database.
On a REST Controller or Service I would like to set a custim Spring Security @preauthorize in order to check access on method according user rights.

User right is my application to access to a resource (page, service etc...) are specific and handled by an habilitation service call database....
They are not loaded in userDetails.

So, how could I do to configure CustomPermissionEvaluator and do I need to load permissions on login or can call my services in the evaluator.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class ContextSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PermissionEvaluator functionPermissionEvaluator() {
        return new XxxPermissionEvaluator ();
    }

    @Bean
    protected DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(this.functionPermissionEvaluator());
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

Evaluator

```
@Component
public class XxxPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object entity, Object permission) {
        Optional<String> optionalUserId = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin(authentication);
        return optionalUserId.map(userId -> {
            EntityValidatorFactory entityValidatorFactory = applicationContext.getBean(EntityValidatorFactory.class);
            EntityValidator entityValidator = entityValidatorFactory.get(entity);
            return entityValidator.isUserAllowedToEntity(userId, entity, (String) permission);
        }).orElse(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable serializable, String s, Object o) {
        throw new PrimaClaimsRuntimeException("hasPermission is not implemented.");
    }
}
```

My pb is my custom evaluator call a database service it has to inject it. 
Or it's a bit weird in a configuration class to injects service etc... scanned else where by the same configuration

So calling a service is it a good way you should I load permission on Login in userDetail...?

Comment: It depend on, where are the data you need to process the permissions.

Comment: Data are database. But if necessary it's possible to loaded and stored when user logs in

Comment: It's possible, you can make some cache in your app.